# Is there an easy way of naming tags of Wordpress elements so I can manipulate them with an imported Jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am developing an e-commerce clothing WordPress site for a client. They've given me a strict design including a page titled 'LookBook' which displays images in a tab gallery style. Creating this with a tradition HTML page I would develop a list of thumbnail sized images and a container for the featured image. Using jQuery, I would add an onClick function to all elements of the list to make their image source = the container background image source. This would mean whatever image selected will become the feature image until another selection is made.

In Wordpress I understand how to insert image blocks in to a list (a container block) and that there is existing plugins where I can import jQuery scripts, but my main problem is when writing the scripts to manipulate these images I don't know what tag elements to reference or how to rename the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When exploring the plug-ins that WordPress offer, I came across a plug-in named 'code snippet' which allows you to insert HTML, JavaScript and CSS all in one file and then import it directly into your WordPress site with a shortcode. This essentially gives you the functionality to create custom WordPress blocks so you can fully customise a page as much as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).